# If $2^X = 2^Y$ then, $X=Y$?

Tags: proof-verification

I'm blocked on a question about sets:

if $2^X= 2^Y$ holds for two sets $X$ and $Y$, then can we say that  $X=Y$ ?

I know how to prove it with two integers a and b but how can i show it with two sets?

Thanks

Comment: I think you're confused about the notation $2^X$. For a set $X$, we denote the power set $\mathcal P(X)$ of $X$ as $2^X$.

Comment: It's most literally interpreted as the set of functions $X \to \{0,1\}$.

Comment: Are you talking about equations between cardinalities? Or does $2^X = 2^Y$ mean that $X$ and $Y$ have the same power set?

Comment: @PatrickStevens, each element of the set of functions $X\to\{0,1\}$ can be thought of (or more precisely, can be mapped) to a unique subset of $X$ (we have an obvious bijection here). So, it's equivalent to think of $2^X$ as $\mathcal P(X)$.

Comment: Hi, i wanted to mean that 2^X is for "2 to the power of X" equals to "2 to the power of Y" with X,Y sets

Comment: So if it's an equation between the power sets, Patrick Stevens has given you an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. We show that $X \subseteq Y$, and then $Y \subseteq X$ follows by symmetry.

Let $x \in X$. Then $\{x\} \in \mathcal{P}(X)$. So, since $\mathcal{P}(X) = \mathcal{P}(Y)$, have $\{x\} \in \mathcal{P}(Y)$; so $x \in Y$.

---

Actually, faster way which skips out one quantifier: $X \subseteq X$, so $X \in \mathcal{P}(X)$, so $X \in \mathcal{P}(Y)$, so $X \subseteq Y$.